# How to fix Internal 500 Error on Visual Studio

Tags: c#, httpclient

I'm having a little problem. Why is that I'm getting internal 500 error on Visual Studio?
But on Visual Studio Code I don't getting any error and I successfully getting the token.

Here's my current code. Could you tell me where is my error? because I can't find the error even if I do a debugging.

```
   private static string loginUrl = "https://site.tv/user/login";
    private static string RequestVerificationToken { get; set; } = "y5cc9W5WNIdQnNVrkmNlwu0IdyaMs8p3mWFDlkK2S3ns_xTX7lH2j6YMec0MFnOItl_t7bgKEtFgOQJQ2CGluYdZdOE1";
    private static string BodyVerificationToken { get; set; } = "1b0lTOz_7zBnqHTAw6-K0YATOUUcMfYXXYCPJadz0L5XyDNYPBY832N9UEAWYIKlLpj69XdlD34dBhqNw3BnqhQVVpU1";

    private static readonly CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

    private static readonly HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        CookieContainer = cookieContainer,
        AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
        UseCookies = true,
        UseProxy = false,
        Proxy = null
    };

    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

    public static async Task<string> Login(string username, string password)
    {
        var random = RandomHexDigits();
        var boundary = "------WebKitFormBoundary" + random;

        var body = MakeMultipartForm(boundary, new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("__requestverificationtoken", BodyVerificationToken),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("logintype", "email"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", username),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password)
        });

        Uri uri = new Uri(loginUrl, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,uri))
        {
            using (var content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "multipart/form-data"))
            {
                content.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
                content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("multipart/form-data");
                content.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("boundary", $"----WebKitFormBoundary{random}"));
                byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
                content.Headers.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
                request.Content = content;

                return await ResponseMessage(request);
            }
        }
    }
    private static async Task<string> ResponseMessage(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        request.Headers.Accept.Clear();
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        request.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9");
        request.Headers.UserAgent.TryParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36");
        request.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue { MaxAge = new TimeSpan(0), NoCache = true };
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Origin", "https://site.tv");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Sec-Fetch-Site", "same-origin");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "navigate");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Sec-Fetch-User", "?1");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "document");
        request.Headers.Referrer = new Uri("https://site.tv/");
        request.Headers.Host = "site.tv";
        request.Headers.Add("Cookie", $"__RequestVerificationToken={RequestVerificationToken}");
        request.Headers.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");

        using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) { throw new Exception(); }
            return GetCookie(loginUrl, ".GNSAUTH");
        }
    }
```

UPDATE: I see this error when I read the html from the response.

```
the required anti-forgery cookie __requestverificationtoken is not present
```

Comment: Why would this code execute any different under visual studio or code? All that aside, if you need to determine why a remote service is returning an internal error in some situations, i suggest you use the appropriate tool to debug the web calls, like fiddler

Comment: I also don't know why. But I used the same code from vscode.

Comment: Already solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed it.

Instead of setting the cookie from the request:

```
request.Headers.Add("Cookie", $"__RequestVerificationToken={RequestVerificationToken}");
```

I just set the cookie to like this and it solved my problem.

```
cookieContainer.Add(uri, new Cookie("__RequestVerificationToken", RequestVerificationToken));
```